# Is pointwise definability of a model of PA equivalent to it being the standard model?

Tags: model-theory, peano-axioms

The standard model of Peano Arithmetic is pointwise definable, because every finite natural number is parameter-free definable. What about the converse? That is, if a model $M$ of PA is pointwise definable, must it be the standard model? Also, bonus question, are there even nonstandard models of PA which are pointwise definable, and some that are not?

Comment: The last question is easy: for instance, any uncountable model is trivally not pointwise definable.

Comment: I closed this question as a duplicate of your previous question on this topic, because the answer is contained in Noah Schweber's answer there. Noah wrote: "In particular, this means that every completion $T$ of $\mathsf{PA}$ has a unique-up-to-isomorphism model in which *every* element is parameter-freely definable, and unless $T=\mathsf{TA}$ (true arithmetic) this model will be nonstandard."

Comment: So to be perfectly clear: A model of true arithmetic is pointwise definable if and only if it's the standard model. But every other completion of PA has a pointwise definable model (which is not the standard model of PA!) and many non-pointwise definable models.